# Finding Closest Sibling in a BST efficiently

Tags: java, interview-questions

Trying to print the closest sibling in a BST. How can I improve on this algorithm in terms of space/time efficiency? Please point out any potential bugs too! I'd appreciate that.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class ClosestSibling {

        public static void printClosestSibling(Node node, List<Node> levelNodes) {

            if (node == null) return;
            levelNodes.add(node);

            while (!levelNodes.isEmpty() || !(levelNodes.size()==0)) {

                printSiblings(levelNodes);

                levelNodes=replaceWithChildNodes(levelNodes);
            }

        }

        public static List<Node> replaceWithChildNodes(List<Node> levelNodes) {
            List<Node> newLevelNodes = new ArrayList<Node>();

            for (Node node : levelNodes) {

                if (node.left != null) {
                    newLevelNodes.add(node.left);
                }
                if (node.right != null) {
                    newLevelNodes.add(node.right);
                }
            }

            return newLevelNodes;
        }

        public static void printSiblings(List<Node> levelnodes) {

            for (int i = 0; i < levelnodes.size() - 1; i++) {
                System.out.println(levelnodes.get(i).data + ":" + levelnodes.get(i + 1).data);
            }
            System.out.println(levelnodes.get(levelnodes.size()-1).data + ":" + "null");
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            BinarySearchTree bst = new BinarySearchTree();
            bst.root = bst.addNode(10, bst.root);
            bst.addNode(20, bst.root);
            bst.addNode(5, bst.root);
            bst.addNode(2, bst.root);
            bst.addNode(40, bst.root);
            bst.addNode(15, bst.root);
            bst.addNode(8, bst.root);
            System.out.println();
            bst.printTree(bst.root);
            System.out.println();
            printClosestSibling(bst.root, new ArrayList<Node>());

        }

    }
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible to properly review this code unless you post the API of `BinarySearchTree` and `Node`.

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while (!levelNodes.isEmpty() || !(levelNodes.size()==0)) {
```

This is duplicate code; `isEmpty` checks for `size() == 0`.

```
System.out.println(levelnodes.get(levelnodes.size()-1).data + ":" + "null");
```

Here, in `printSiblings`, you can get `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if the list is empty.

I also don't understand why `printClosestSibling` takes a `List<Node>` argument. 
Either you want to take 1 node to print the closestSibling of, in which case you should remove the argument and accept a single node, or you want to take a list of nodes, in which case I'd recommend overloading:

```
public static void printClosestSibling(Node... nodes){
    printClosestSibling(Arrays.asList(nodes));
}

public static void printClosestSibling(List<Node> nodes){
    ...
}
```

Keep in mind that you need to also deal with the fact that `levelNodes` could contain `null`. You would get NullPointerException right now. Either explain via the documentation, or fail-fast and check the list of nodes for `null` before running your entire algorithm.